# List of Cassandra error codes

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax, cql

While using the datastax node.js driver I'm getting an exception code as documented under http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver-dse/1.4/api/module.errors/class.ResponseError/.

However I cannot find any documentation about all available exception codes. Anybody an idea where to find?

Comment: Look in the Errors module for a list of possible errors that the Node.js driver can produce

Comment: A found it while checking responseErrorCodes at runtime. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that the code values are specifically documented anywhere but you could always look at the [ExceptionCode](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/exceptions/ExceptionCode.java) source for the version of Cassandra you are working with.

On trunk this lists the errors as:

```
SERVER_ERROR    (0x0000),
PROTOCOL_ERROR  (0x000A),

BAD_CREDENTIALS (0x0100),

// 1xx: problem during request execution
UNAVAILABLE         (0x1000),
OVERLOADED          (0x1001),
IS_BOOTSTRAPPING    (0x1002),
TRUNCATE_ERROR      (0x1003),
WRITE_TIMEOUT       (0x1100),
READ_TIMEOUT        (0x1200),
READ_FAILURE        (0x1300),
FUNCTION_FAILURE    (0x1400),
WRITE_FAILURE       (0x1500),
CDC_WRITE_FAILURE   (0x1600),

// 2xx: problem validating the request
SYNTAX_ERROR    (0x2000),
UNAUTHORIZED    (0x2100),
INVALID         (0x2200),
CONFIG_ERROR    (0x2300),
ALREADY_EXISTS  (0x2400),
UNPREPARED      (0x2500);
```

Comment: I'm running version 3.11.1 of Cassandra and getting e.g. 9216 with message "Cannot add existing keyspace" while trying to create an existing keyspace again. Doesn't seem to be part of the list above.

Comment: The error your getting is coming from the DSE Node.js driver and not he Cassandra core

Answer (score 1):

The response error codes are not properly documented in the driver, I've created a ticket for it: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/NODEJS-418

In the meantime, you should be getting code completion on your IDE (VS Code / WebStorm) and/or [look at the code](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/v3.3.0/lib/types/index.js#L218-L240):

```
const responseErrorCodes = {
  serverError:            0x0000,
  protocolError:          0x000A,
  badCredentials:         0x0100,
  unavailableException:   0x1000,
  overloaded:             0x1001,
  isBootstrapping:        0x1002,
  truncateError:          0x1003,
  writeTimeout:           0x1100,
  readTimeout:            0x1200,
  readFailure:            0x1300,
  functionFailure:        0x1400,
  writeFailure:           0x1500,
  syntaxError:            0x2000,
  unauthorized:           0x2100,
  invalid:                0x2200,
  configError:            0x2300,
  alreadyExists:          0x2400,
  unprepared:             0x2500
};
```

To check against a certain error code, you should use something like:

```
if (err.code === cassandra.types.responseErrorCodes.syntaxError) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, exactly. Thank you!